# Count open cases with and without time cut-off

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have this dataset with variables Person, RelevantCase, StartDate, and EndDate:

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c('111','334','334','334','334','334','888','888','888','888','888','888','888','888'), 
                 RelevantCase = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1), 
                 StartDate = c('2017-03-04','2015-11-14','2018-04-26','2020-01-24','2020-01-25','2020-02-29','2015-08-09',
                          '2015-08-09','2018-04-10','2019-09-20','2020-06-30','2020-11-01','2021-08-13','2022-11-11'),
                 EndDate = c('2017-12-12','2022-01-25','2020-03-01','2021-02-24','2020-01-30','2022-02-02','2019-10-20',
                             '2019-10-30','2018-10-10','2021-10-10','2020-07-20','2022-11-20','2021-11-12','2023-01-01')
)
```

I want to create two new variables:

1. A count of the number of relevant open cases per Person. That is, I want to count how many relevant cases have

   1.1. StartDates *before* the current cases' StartDate **and**

   1.2. EndDates *on or after* the current StartDate.

By "relevant case" I mean that I want to only count observations with RelevantCase==1.

2. A count of the number of relevant open cases per Person that started within the last two years of the current StartDate. So, this is the same as the first new variable, but it will not count relevant open cases with StartDates that are more than two years prior to the current StartDate.

The resulting dataset should look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Person = c('111','334','334','334','334','334','888','888','888','888','888','888','888','888'), 
                 RelevantCase = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1), 
                 StartDate = c('2017-03-04','2015-11-14','2018-04-26','2020-01-24','2020-01-25','2020-02-29','2015-08-09',
                               '2015-08-09','2018-04-10','2019-09-20','2020-06-30','2020-11-01','2021-08-13','2022-11-11'),
                 EndDate = c('2017-12-12','2022-01-25','2020-03-01','2021-02-24','2020-01-30','2022-02-02','2019-10-20',
                             '2019-10-30','2018-10-10','2021-10-10','2020-07-20','2022-11-20','2021-11-12','2023-01-01'),
                 NumberOpenCases = c(0,0,1,2,2,2,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                 NumberOpenCases_2y = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the number of relevant open cases by looping over `StartDate` column within each group and checking for the conditions desired.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(StartDate = as.Date(StartDate),
         EndDate = as.Date(EndDate)) %>% 
  arrange(Person, StartDate, EndDate) %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  mutate(NumberOpenCases    = map_int(StartDate, ~sum(StartDate < .x  & 
                                                      EndDate >= .x & 
                                                      RelevantCase == 1)),
         NumberOpenCases_2y = map_int(StartDate, ~sum(StartDate < .x  & 
                                                      EndDate >= .x & 
                                                      RelevantCase == 1 &
                                                      .x - StartDate < 730)))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 6
#> # Groups:   Person [3]
#>    Person RelevantCase StartDate  EndDate    NumberOpenCases NumberOpenCases_2y
#>    <chr>         <dbl> <date>     <date>               <int>              <int>
#>  1 111               0 2017-03-04 2017-12-12               0                  0
#>  2 334               1 2015-11-14 2022-01-25               0                  0
#>  3 334               1 2018-04-26 2020-03-01               1                  0
#>  4 334               0 2020-01-24 2021-02-24               2                  1
#>  5 334               1 2020-01-25 2020-01-30               2                  1
#>  6 334               0 2020-02-29 2022-02-02               2                  1
#>  7 888               1 2015-08-09 2019-10-20               0                  0
#>  8 888               0 2015-08-09 2019-10-30               0                  0
#>  9 888               1 2018-04-10 2018-10-10               1                  0
#> 10 888               0 2019-09-20 2021-10-10               1                  0
#> 11 888               0 2020-06-30 2020-07-20               0                  0
#> 12 888               1 2020-11-01 2022-11-20               0                  0
#> 13 888               0 2021-08-13 2021-11-12               1                  1
#> 14 888               1 2022-11-11 2023-01-01               1                  0
```